# Expression to Set Properties on Existing Object Instance

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

How can I use `Expression` to set properties on an instance of an object I already have? I don't want to create a new object, so `Expression.New` where you can pass in member initializers won't work.

This is not a duplicate of [How to set property value using Expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601707/how-to-set-property-value-using-expressions) because that takes an `Expression` and sets properties via `Reflection`.

I have an existing `object` and want to create an `Expression` where I can set properties. That expression will then get compiled into a `delegate` to execute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set property value using Expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601707/how-to-set-property-value-using-expressions)

Comment: Expression.Assign into  Expression.Property of your object (either as a ConstantExpression or ParameterExpression depending on how you're using it) passing the PropertyInfo of the property you want to assign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about:

```
public class User {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public static void Main()
{
    var user = new User();
    var assigner = GetAssigner<User, string>(u => u.Name);
    assigner.Compile()(user, "Joe");
    Console.WriteLine(user.Name);
}

public static Expression<Action<TClass, TValue>> GetAssigner<TClass, TValue>(Expression<Func<TClass, TValue>> propertyAccessor){
    var prop = ((MemberExpression)propertyAccessor.Body).Member;
    var typeParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TClass));
    var valueParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TValue));
    return Expression.Lambda<Action<TClass, TValue>>(
        Expression.Assign(
            Expression.MakeMemberAccess(typeParam, prop),
            valueParam), typeParam, valueParam);

}
```

Remember that the expression is just a definition of what should be done, you have to compile it to a delegate to be able to invoke it.

Comment: The combination of `Expression.Assign` with `Expression.MakeMemberAccess` is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using [MemberAssignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberassignment(v=vs.110).aspx) to set the value of the member(s)?

> Represents assignment operation for a field or property of an object.

Important note in the remarks, however: you can't create these directly. Instead,

> Use the [Bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.bind(v=vs.110).aspx) factory methods to create a MemberAssignment.
>   A MemberAssignment has the BindingType property equal to [Assignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberbindingtype(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I have a list of `MemberAssignment`s. How do I create an `Expression` to assign those to an existing object? I can do it when creating a new object via `Expression.New`, but I don't know how to do it with an existing object.

Comment: It’s been a while, but I seem to recall `MemberAssignment` being specifically for object initializer expressions, like `new X { Member = y }`.  A plain old `Assign(Property(x, "Member"), y),` should be fine.

Comment: The docs don't mention object initializer expressions, perhaps you're thinking of [MemberInitExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberinitexpression(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @JoshClose pass the property to get/set as a ParameterExpression after all, property setter are really just method calls accepting a parameter corresponding to the value to update