# Setting property without knowing target type at compile time

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to set the property value on an object without knowing the object type at compile time; I want it to be fast (i.e. not using Reflection every time); I know property name and type.

The fastest way (afaik) is to use delegates; so this is what I have so far:

```
class User // this is an example.. Assume I don't know which type this is.
 {
    public string Name {get;set;}   
 }

public static Action<object, object> CreatePropertySetter(Type targetType, string propertyName)
{
    ParameterExpression targetObjParamExpr = Expression.Parameter(targetType);
    ParameterExpression valueParamExpr = Expression.Parameter(targetType.GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType);

    MemberExpression propertyExpr = Expression.Property(targetObjParamExpr, propertyName);

    BinaryExpression assignExpr = Expression.Assign(targetObjParamExpr, valueParamExpr);

    Action<object, object> result = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(assignExpr, targetObjParamExpr, valueParamExpr).Compile();
    return result;
}
```

Then I'd make this call:

```
User user = new User();
var userNameSetter = CreatePropertySetter(user.GetType(), "Name");
userNameSetter(user, "Bob");
```

However, it doesn't like the fact that I pass User type object instead of Object, and fails with "*ParameterExpression of type 'User' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Object*".

I'm new to expression trees, so a bit lost here. Why can't it cast User to object ? Do I need a cast somewhere ?

The "Action" doesn't look great either; would be nicer to just return a delegate taking arguments (User user, string propertyValue). Again, not sure how to accomplish that. Actually, I've tried it with Delegate.CreateDelegate, but it invokes using .Invoke() method, which is slow (is this the only way?); same with Expression.Lambda (non-generic).

Any thoughts ?

Also, is there a good (better than msdn) documentation on Expression Trees?  The msdn version really lacks details.

Comment: `TL;DR` Don't do this. Write clear concise questions with the relevant information and details instead.

Comment: Edited. Though it was a summary of the whole question, and had enough details to provide an answer, imo.

Comment: This is a bit off to the side, but it feels like you're a C++ programmer who is used to using templates, but can't now in C#.  This would be trivial in C++.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for [Convert.ChangeType Method (Object, Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx)

Comment: Is `User` a value type or reference type?

Comment: @kevin - nah, I haven't touched C++ in a looong while.. since college :)

Comment: @Thomas - I guess we can say it's a reference type just for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Now if anyone could share the link to some decent docs on expression trees - this would be great!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use Expression, then: `Convert`...

```
static void Main()
{
    var setter = CreatePropertySetter(typeof (User), "Name");
    var obj = new User();
    setter(obj, "Fred");
}
public static Action<object, object> CreatePropertySetter(Type targetType, string propertyName)
{
    var target = Expression.Parameter(typeof (object), "obj");
    var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof (object), "value");
    var property = targetType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    var body = Expression.Assign(
        Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(target, property.DeclaringType), property),
        Expression.Convert(value, property.PropertyType));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(body, target, value);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

However! You might want to look at [FastMember](http://code.google.com/p/fast-member/) (also available on NuGet), which wraps **all** of this up for you very conveniently (and uses raw IL for silly craziness).

If you want to use a typed delegate, you'll need to know the types in advance. If you **know** the types, you could add some generic:

```
static void Main()
{
    var setter = CreatePropertySetter<User,string>("Name");
    var obj = new User();
    setter(obj, "Fred");
}
public static Action<TType, TValue> CreatePropertySetter<TType, TValue>(string propertyName)
{
    var target = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TType), "obj");
    var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TValue), "value");
    var property = typeof(TType).GetProperty(propertyName);
    var body = Expression.Assign(
        Expression.Property(target, property),
        value);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<TType, TValue>>(body, target, value);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Comment: This is great!:) Thanks ! I had something very much along same lines as your second example, but was struggling with making it more generic, though.  I think I see what I did wrong..

Thanks for the hint on FastMember, i'll definitely take a look.

Comment: Fantastic, been looking for something like this the whole day. All I could find were items with typed delegates! Thanks!